# Display PDF in UIWebView using loadData

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, nsdata

I am trying to display a PDF I have stored locally in a UIWebView. This is how I currently attempt to do this:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.url]) {
LOG_ERROR(@"Couldn't load local file. File at path: %@ doesn't exist", self.url);
        return; 
}

nsurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.url];
LOG_DEBUG(@"data length:%d",[data length]);
[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

I have also tried passing nil for textEncoding, as well as using UIWebView's loadRequest. The result is a UIWebView that displays a blank page. No errors occur in the UIWebView delegate method. The strange thing is that data has the correct length, in bytes, for the PDF I am trying to display, which means the file is being found and loaded correctly.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going wrong here or how I can better debug this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below you can find two different approaches to open a `.pdf` file on your `UIWebView`; one from a `url` and one as `NSData`:

```
if (self.pdfDataToLoad) //Loading the pdf as NSData
{ 
    [self.webView loadData:self.pdfData 
                  MIMEType:@"application/pdf" 
          textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" 
                   baseURL:nil];
}
else  //Open the pdf from a URL 
{ 
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: This. Everyone is saying "you don't need it, just load the file URL!". But in my case, I have the PDF as `NSData()` in RAM (I just rendered it from HTML) and it is pointless to save once to a temporary file. Thank you for answering the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was something to do with the file format of the PDFs. I edited them using Illustrator and re-saved them. I guess Mobile Safari doesn't like the way Illustrator formatted the files because each was blank when viewed using the simulator's browser (although I could open the PDFs in regular Safari just fine).

The solution was to open the PDFs using Preview and re-save them. After running each PDF through the Preview save routine I was able to get each PDF to display in a UIWebView without changing any of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need NSData to load local file, loadRequest should work directly with NSURL

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl]];
```

I can only suggest to make NSURL like that

```
nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That wasn't related to my solution, but I did end up doing it the way you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`NSData` is used to load the pdf files when they are stored locally in any of the directories.
To load the pdf which was in your application, use the following code .

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileNameHere" 
                                             ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```